# Use variable as php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I want to know if variables can be used in an array. see below (*$userArray = array($usersBought);*)

```
    $user = "Darren";
    $usersBought = $row['usersBought'];
    $userArray = array($usersBought);
    if (in_array($user, $userArray)) {
      $button = "yes";
    }
```

If this can work, what should the text be in the database? I have tried this...

```
"Darren","Adam","Coral"
Darren,Adam,Coral
Darren Adam Coral
```

This array is in a while loop and displays multiple unordered lists on a page through the loop. That is why i have the $usersBought = $row['usersBought']; there

Comment: What is `$row['usersBought']`?

Comment: from the MySQL result...

Comment: have you tried, $userArray = $row['usersBought']; ??

Comment: $usersBought = $row['usersBought']; its already there

Comment: well, $row['usersBought'] is an array, so $usersBought is an array. Then you're adding this array in another array, $userArray = array($usersBought); just replace $userArray = $usersBought and try once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your database to be properly normalized, you should structure your tables in such a way that you are not storing an array in the database and instead each user is a row in a table.

To answer your question however, you need to use the `explode()` function.

```
//$row['usersBought'] = "Darren,Adam,Coral"; <- Example 
$user = "Darren";
$usersBought = $row['usersBought'];
$userArray = explode(",", $usersBought);
if (in_array($user, $userArray)) {
  $button = "yes";
}
```

In the example above it assumes that the users are separated by commas, but you can change the first parameter to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you store your data like this: `Darren,Adam,Coral`
the right solution would be:

```
$user = "Darren";
$usersBought = explode(",",$row['usersBought']); //Just choose the right delimiter.


if (in_array($user, $userArray)) {
  //Ok proceed.
}
```

Also, you may use function `preg_grep` that will allow you to check in case-insensitive manner.

```
$in_array = preg_grep("/{$user}/i" , $usersBought);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $row['usersBought'] is itself an array (which I doubt) then the function you are looking for is called [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

and your code would look like:

```
$userArray = array_merge($usersBought);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example: Database test, table Users

```
ID|Name|
1|Emilio|
2|Darren|
```

After the connect to DB you should do something like this:

```
$user = 'Darren';
$query = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Name ='$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count >= 1){
    $button = "yes";
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing code here, what is `%s`, `mysqli_query()` needs parameters, etc.